# Choropleth Plotting polygons with ggplot2 R on a map

Tags: r, ggplot2, gis, ggmap

I realise this has been asked about 100 times prior, but none of the answers I've read so far on SO seem to fit my problem.

I have data. I have the lat and lon values. I've read around about something called sp and made a bunch of shape objects in a dataframe. I have matched this dataframe with the variable I am interested in mapping.

I cannot for the life of me figure out how the hell to get `ggplot2` to draw polygons. Sometimes it wants explicit x,y values (which are a PART of the shape anyway, so seems redundant), or some other shape files externally which I don't actually have. Short of colouring it in with highlighters, I'm at a loss.

if I take an individual sps object (built with the following function after importing, cleaning, and wrangling a shitload of data)

```
createShape = function(sub){
  #This funciton takes the list of lat/lng values and returns a SHAPE which should be plottable on ggmap/ggplot
  tempData = as.data.frame(do.call(rbind, as.list(VICshapes[which(VICshapes$Suburb==sub),] %>% select(coords))[[1]][[1]]))
  names(tempData) = c('lat', 'lng')
  p = Polygon(tempData)
  ps = Polygons(list(p),1)
  sps = SpatialPolygons(list(ps))
  return(sps)
}
```

These shapes are then stored in the same dataframe as my data - which only this afternoon for some reason, I can't even look at, as trying to look at it yields the following error.

```
head(plotdata)
Error in prettyNum(.Internal(format(x, trim, digits, nsmall, width, 3L,  : first argument must be atomic
```

I realise I'm really annoyed at this now, but I've about 70% of a grade riding on this, and my university has nobody capable of assisting.

I have pasted the first few rows of data here - https://pastebin.com/vFqy5m5U - apparently you can't print data with an s4 object - the shape file that I"m trying to plot.

Anyway. I'm trying to plot each of those shapes onto a map. Polygons want an x,y value. I don't have ANY OTHER SHAPE FILES. I created them based on a giant list of lat and long values, and the code chunk above. I'm genuinely at a loss here and don't know what question to even ask. I have the variable of interest based on locality, and the shape for each locality. What am I missing?

edit: [I've pasted the summary data (BEFORE making them into shapes) here. It's a massive list of lat/lng values for EACH tile/area, so it's pretty big...](https://gist.github.com/wotarpelo/91bf2f6c0703820b6b7a981ec057f33d)

Comment: cross-posted (and now answered) on gis.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 0):

Answered on [gis.stackexchange.com](https://gis.stackexchange.com) (link not provided).